# Is making WebGL context object a global/semi-global variable a bad idea?

Tags: webgl

So, my idea is to do something like that (the code is simplified of course):

```
var gl;

function Renderer(canvas) {
     gl = this.gl = canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
}

function Object() {
}

Object.prototype.render = function() {
    ...
    gl.drawElements(...);
}
```

The `gl` variable itself can be placed into a namespace for better consistency, it can also be incapsulated by wrapping all the code into an anonymous function to make sure it won't clash with anything.

I can see one obvious tradeoff here: problems with running multiple WebGL canvases on the same page. But I'm totally fine with it.

Why doing that? Because otherwise it's more painful to call any WebGL functions, you have to pass your renderer as a parameter here and there. That's actually the thing I don't like about Three.js: all the graphics stuff is handled inside a Renderer object, which makes the whole Renderer object huge and complicated.

If using a globally visible context, you don't have to bother about OpenGL constants, you don't have to worry about your renderer object's visibility, and so on.

So, my question is: should I expect any traps with this approach? Aside from potential emptiness of the `gl` variable, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define **bad**

Lots of WebGL programs do this. OpenGL does this by default since the functions are global in scope. In normal OpenGL you have to call `eglMakeCurrent` (or equivalent) to switch contexts which effectively is just doing a hidden `gl = contextToMakeCurrent` under the hood.

So, basically it's up to you. If you think someday you're going to need multiple WebGL contexts then it might be wise to not have your contexts use global variables. But you can always fallback to the `eglMakeCurrent` style of coding. Both have their pluses and minuses.